# What happens if one no longer meets the requirements for an attuned item?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attunement

So, I have a question that's sort of a what-if situation that applies to many different situations, but what happens if the requirements to attune to an item are lost while that item is attuned to you?

For example, say my lawful evil Paladin has Scather, the lawful-evil sword of answering and draws the Balance card from the deck of many things. Now, Scather requires attunement to a lawful-evil person, and balance causes his alignment to become opposite to what it used to be, now becoming Chaotic-Good with Scather still attuned as this happens. Does Scather automatically unattune, or does it remain attuned?

This can also be applied to other attunement requirements such as race and ability scores

Comment: So basically another "constant targetting or not?" question, right? Can you think of example that does not require Deck of Many Things / miracle / wish?

Comment: Certain weapons require attunement by a certain race, if the polymorph spell makes them a different race, even if temporarily, the same would apply

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### The attunement ends

This can be found in the DMG section for magic items. In the [attunement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#Attunement) section (DMG p. 138):

> A creature’s attunement to an item ends if the creature no longer satisfies the prerequisites for attunement

So if you no longer meet the prerequisites the attunement simply ends