# What happens if you no longer meet the Strength requirement for your armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, armor, attunement, artificer-infusions

I recently asked about what happens when you lose requirements for an attuned item ([here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/162556/what-happens-if-one-no-longer-meets-the-requirements-for-an-attuned-item)). Now, I have a slightly different but still related question involving the artificer class' 20th-level ability, which says that you can

> use your reaction to end one of your artificer infusions

One of the artificer infusions is the Belt of Hill Giant Strength, which sets your Strength score to 21. Since heavy armor has a Strength score requirement, **what happens if I un-attune to the belt by ending the infusion and lose the required Strength to wear armor that I have equipped?**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### You don't need the displayed Strength score to *wear* the armor; it prevents your speed from being lowered. Your speed will be reduced if at any time you do not meet the required Strength score.

The section on "[Armor and Shields](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#ArmorandShields)" states:

> ***Heavy Armor.*** Heavy Armor. Heavier armor interferes with the wearer's ability to move quickly, stealthily, and freely. If the Armor table shows "Str 13" or "Str 15" in the Strength column for an armor type, **the armor reduces the wearer's speed by 10 feet unless the wearer has a Strength score equal to or higher than the listed score.**
>
> - *Player's Handbook* (page 144; Chapter 5: Equipment; Armor and Shields)

Not having the requisite Strength score simply means that your speed will be reduced by 10 feet until you meet the requirement again.